# Sqlite database on Mac

Tags: macos, sqlite

How can i download and install sqlite database on Mac? Also does Mac OS X come with sqlite database preinstalled? If yes then how can i find it?

Comment: What do you mean with "download and install sqlite database"? A sqlite database is a file - thats all. There is no "server" or something similar. And every program that will use a sqlite database should have their own tools to get access to this database.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install a development copy (incl. headers) is something like Fink's [sqlite-dev](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/sqlite-dev?doc_id=10.6-x86_64-current-unstable-sqlite-dev-2.8.17-1002) package.  However, you're correct that Mac OS comes with SQLite, in fact [multiple copies](http://sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html).  One is part of Apple's [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

Just get binaries from here http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Or use macports or fink commander to install sqlite package.